# Android Button changing color and incrementing size

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi guys im new in android stuff and i have a problem with a button when color change, because when it changes the button grows a bit and i dont know why. My code of the button click is below.

```
produzirbt.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(38, 198, 219));
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Avaria iniciada.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Xml

```
<Button
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="Pausa"
            android:id="@+id/Pausa"
            android:textSize="50px"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_above="@+id/Avaria"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/terminaliniciado"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/terminaliniciado" />
```

Comment: can you post xml of the button

Comment: Try to Use wrap_content and remove any pading in xml ..hope this helps

Comment: Your question is not `android studio` related. Tag removed.

Comment: maby because of your style. Set the background to a random color in your xml. or try without the style param. Or try to set the style new in your progamm, the same way you want it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to keep button size use `setColorFilter()` method.

In your case:

```
produzirbt.getBackground().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.your_color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your button by default has a backgrond definded by some xml file. It contains backround color, corner radiuses and padding. Then in java code you change this style to plain color and padding becomes zero. To prevent size changing you should define base background with a color. Like this:

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="Pausa"
        android:id="@+id/Pausa"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:background="@color/my_button_color"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Avaria"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/terminaliniciado"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/terminaliniciado" />
```

A the same time using color for button is a hacky method. It'll be better to define normal style as [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html#CustomBackground) says.